# Using HMAC SHA256 to protect payment files in local trusted network

Tags: hmac, sha-256

in a project that I am working on we have been tasked with eliminating PGP while providing sufficient security to protect payment files only within the Company's trusted network.  We arrived at HMAC SHA256.  Assuming that we can keep the key private and refresh the (128 bit) key annually,  can someone comment on how difficult it would be to compute the key if an attacker got the plaintext and the hash?  The files on average are about 2mb in size.

Answer (score 2):

With regards to the algorithm, HMAC-SHA256 is considered *very secure*. As with most symmetric algorithms it can probably not be *proven secure*, but that should not worry you overmuch.

The most important security consideration with HMAC is to use a *time consistent compare* when verifying the authentication tag. A 256 bit key could be considered for the simple reason that the overhead won't make any difference when ~2MB files are being protected.

It's probably better to focus on other parts of the system security and make sure you implement the key management well.

Comment: Maarten, thanks very much for the reply! I'm not going to pretend to know what a time consistent compare is - my understanding was that the endpoint in our private network that would be authenticating the HMAC hash would (of course) have the same private key and would recompute the HMAC SHA256 hash and then compare newly computed hash to original hash. Is this not correct or am I missing something?

Comment: No, although you normally talk about *secret keys* instead of private keys for symmetric algorithms. That last compare should be consistent in time, i.e. the compare should not stop at the first bit/byte that is different. Usually that should be taken care of by a *verify* function in the API, but please check.

Comment: Thanks again Mararten - I should have said secret key and not private key.  In your opinion, if  I have a 256 bit secret key created with a PRF,  and I create an HMAC on a 2mb file  and then the file and computed SHA256 HMAC are comprimised,  how long should I expect (without the use of quantum computing)  my key to remain uncomprimised?

Comment: The timing attacks are on the HMAC value itself, not on the key. The key can only be found by reversing the hash, which should be impossible. It could be that some side channel attacks are able to find the key value by studying the initial rounds of the hash, but as the running doesn't depend on the values of the bits much, that would be a pretty good trick to pull off.

Comment: Could you expand more on how a timing attack on the comparison with the tag would leak any information about the key, or even about the message?  Unless all processing done after verification is also time consistent, I don't see how knowing how many common bytes one hash has to another reveals anything (unless there's a weakness in the hash itself).  What does the 1 in 256 times the comparison takes two bytes instead of one, or the 1 in 65536 times it takes three bytes reveal?

Comment: Also, I don't know if you want to mention pre-computing the inner and outer hashes of the HMAC to reduce overhead (with the saved hash states needing to be kept as secure as the key).

Comment: if the comparison leaks timing information, an attacker could brute-force one byte at a time to get a correct HMAC for any message with ~4096 (at most 8192) requests.